# Check external page in PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have created a WordPress plugin that uses my website API.

In the admin settings page of this plugin I want to show the current status of the service (UP or DOWN).

I can manually create a file in my main server (different server from the API server) with the value of current status:
http://www.example.com/status.php

I don't think using PHP `fopen` or `iframe` is a good idea because webmasters may run this plugin on a server with strict policies about these.

What would be the best universal way (PHP, Javascript ...) to show "UP" or "DOWN" inside the plugin admin page in WordPress?

Comment: *I have created a WordPress plugin that uses my website API.* Why don't you have a call that returns the status of your service in your API ? I mean it's the cleanest way!

Comment: If API service is corrupted or down, it wouldn't deliver the status.

Comment: Yes, which means **DOWN**, am I right ?

Comment: What teeyo is trying to say, just catch errors from your API and work around them. If you get a network error, this clearly means your server is down.

Comment: @rndus2r exactly bro

Comment: That's not a solution because API structure and service are already developed. Editing it would be a nightmare. I hoped there was a quick manual method by reading external pages.

Comment: How do you want to read your API page when it's down?

Comment: Besides that you don't need to touch your API at all, you can just work with what you already have. Just change your WP Plugin.

Comment: http://www.example.com/status.php is not my API page. That is a static file I can manually update and it's hosted on a different server.

Comment: "Editing it would be a nightmare" - then you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just include the file.

```
<?php
//status.php
$status = 'UP';
```

-

```
<?php    
//somwhere else
include 'status.php'
echo $status;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is not a universal method. Just tested on a website and got an error:
Warning: include(): https:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_include=0

Comment: It seems like his API and WP are on 2 different server. So if the API Server is down, this won't help

Comment: I see, probably best to let your client determine the staus then rather than the API to provide it. If your client cant connect to the API, it is down, and the client can output that.